# How to cut down RAM consumption when moving a picture inside a picturebox?

Tags: c#, memory, winforms

I'm trying to do a "googlemaps effect" this way:
I have a huuge picture so I cut a reasonably big picture out of it (2000x2000). Let us call it cachedImage. 
Now I want to be able to drag and move this picture inside a picturebox. I do it by changing the position of a topleft point (TLPoint)  within cachedImage and then cachedImage.clone()-ing a rectanglular area with the given TLPoint into the picturebox area. So that every time a picture moves I call a DrawSelection() method with a new position of a TopLeft Point in an argument.
THe program then crashes because of large memory consomnation(crashes of the clone() function on line 282).
 Could you please help me out with that?

The code of the file is here https://github.com/novellizator/path-planner/blob/master/TomyMaps/TomyMaps/Map.cs

Could you please help how to make it more memory-effective? What should I replace the Bitmap.clone() function with?

Comment: Whenever doing drag-drop operations, consider it a rule of thumb to deal with the source object's UI representation rather than the object itself. Consider caching a thumbnail of the large image and use that during the dragging life cycle.